# Oracle Unable to Read Globally Accessible (777) Dump File

Tags: linux, oracle

I'm trying to import an Oracle dump file, and despite granting global rwx permissions on the files, I'm still getting a permission errors when running the import.

Here's the whole process I've run through:

```
# Create the dump directory with the dump file, and grant 777 permissions
mkidr -p /home/vagrant/dump
mv /home/vagrant/data.dmp /home/vagrant/dump
chmod -R 777 /home/vagrant/dump

# Check the file permissions

# drwsrwsrwx. vagrant vagrant dump
# -rwxrwxrwx. vagrant vagrant dump/data.dmp

# Add the directory to Oracle
sqlplus system/vagrant
CREATE DIRECTORY DUMP_DIR AS '/home/vagrant/dump';
exit

# Try importing the data   
impdp system/vagrant dumpfile=data.dmp directory=DUMP_DIR nologfile=y
```

And let the keyboard smashing begin...

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-31640: unable to open dump file "/home/vagrant/dump/data.dmp" for read
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 13: Permission denied
Additional information: 3
```

Note: I'm entirely aware that these permissions and passwords are terrible for security, but since I'm just trying to run some experimental analysis on a publicly available data set, I don't really care.

Comment: I don't think `USERID` is a valid parameter for `impdp`.  Try changing it to: `impdp system/vagrant dumpfile=...` and see if that works?

Comment: Make's no difference.

Comment: How about the /home directory? Does the user, under which the database is installed, has read and execute permissions on it?

Comment: Don't 777 permissions imply that any user has `rwx` access to the files despite user/group?

Comment: Yes, if that user can get to the file in order to access it. It does not matter that the file has 777 permissions, if the directory in which it is located is 600, for example. In order to get to the file you need to be able to enter each directory in the path. Check the permissions for each of: /home and /homde/vagrant.

Comment: Have you checked that the first command you use is `mkidr` and not `mkdir` ??? Can this be the source of your trouble?

Comment: @Mihail That was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your script says `mkidr` instead of `mkdir`.

This way, you don't create the directory, when you move the file to the supposed dir, it only renames the file, making it appear (as a file, not a directory) `/home/vagrant/dump` with the right permissions (except the `d` char at the beginning) and, of course, you cannot search it for files, as it's not a directory, but a file.  This will also impede oracle to execute successfully the `CREATE DIRECTORY DUMP_DIR AS '/home/vagrant/dump';` as there's a file there with that name.

By the way, to access a file, you don't only need read access in the file inode, but also execute permission `x` in all the directories followed along the path (in this case `/home`, `/home/vagrant` and `/home/vagrant/dump` ---this last one is a file, not a directory---).  In this case, it's `ora` (the user oracle runs as) the user that must be checked.

I suggest you to impersonate as the user `ora` and try to read the file if that doesn't work, from the same directory where the database runs, and using the same path as it uses to open the file.

Comment: Nice catch! Unfortunately, that was a typo. I made in the SO question.

Comment: Then follow the other hints I gave in my answer... there can be the solution.  Does the user oracle is running on behalf have execute permissions in all directories to the file in question?